# MySQL right join two tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: hospitals, inspections, and issues. A hospital can have zero or more inspections. Inspections can have zero or more issues. I need to get a table that has all violations with the hospital that they were observed in as well as the date.  Tables look like:

```
Business Table b
----------------------------
|id|name|address|city|state|

Inspection Table i
---------------------
|id|business_id|date|

Issue Table v
-----------------------------------
|id|business_id|inspection_id|desc|
```

What I need, ordered by `i.date desc` is:

```
Query result
--------------------------------
|b.name|b.address|i.date|v.desc|
```

There will be more than one issue per inspection so I need a row for each as above. That's what I am getting, but the latest inspection data is returned for every issue even though they were observed on different dates.

Here is what I have for my query:

```
SELECT b.business_name AS Name, b.address, b.city, b.state, i.date, v.desc
FROM business_table AS b
RIGHT JOIN inspection_table i ON i.business_id = b.id
RIGHT JOIN issue_table v ON v.inspection_id = i.id
ORDER BY i.date DESC
```

Comment: You really want `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`, not `RIGHT`!!!

Comment: Try LEFT JOINs instead of those RIGHT JOINs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT b.business_name AS Name, b.address, b.city, b.state, i.date, v.desc
FROM issue_table v 
LEFT JOIN inspection_table i ON i.id = v.inspection_id
LEFT JOIN business_table AS b ON v.business_id = b.id
ORDER BY v.business_id, i.date DESC
```